# Ways to pass values into Javascript options objects using ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Options objects (so called) are used to collect static parameters from the page for a javascript file to operate on. What are the best ways to pass dynamic values from the page into a javascript options object?
Eg how should you insert a value for MyAlbumID in the following

```
MyOptionsObject({
    flashvars: {
        xmlFilePath: "http://myurl.com/images.php?album=" + MyAlbumID
    })​
```

Where MyAlbumID is obtained from:

```
 var albumspan = document.getElementById("lblMyAlbum");
 var albumtextnode = albumspan.firstChild;
 var MyAlbumID = albumtextnode.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem?

```
onDynamicAction(function(){
    // ensure that the DOM is loaded when that action happens

    var myAlbumID = document.getElementById("lblMyAlbum").firstChild.data;
    // lets hope there is an element with that id and a textnode,
    // so that this threw no error

    MyOptionsObject ({
      flashvars: {
        xmlFilePath: "http://myurl.com/images.php?album=" + myAlbumID
      } // missing bracket, btw.
    });
    // set a new object
})
```